# Optimizing the performance of MySQL regarding aggregation

Tags: mysql, performance, aggregate

I'm trying to optimize a report query, as most of report queries this one incorporates aggregation. Since the size of table is considerable and growing, I need to tend to its performance.

For example, I have a table with three columns: `id`, `name`, `action`. And I would like to count the number of actions each name has done:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY name;
```

As simple as it gets, I can't run it in a acceptable time. It might take 30 seconds and there's no index, whatsoever, I can add which is taken into account, nevertheless improves it.

When I run `EXPLAIN` on the above query, it never uses any of indices of the table, i.e. an index on `name`.

Is there any way to improve the performance of aggregation? Why the index is not used?

**[UPDATE]**

Here's the `EXPLAIN`'s output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4025567 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

And here is the table's schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `action` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `inx` (`name`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you post the schema and the explain please?

Comment: what happens if you use COUNT(1) instead of COUNT(id)? In my database it helps...

Comment: @NevilleK I've added the extra info.

Comment: @marcosh No that doesn't help at all. My question is why the index is not used and I can not see how `COUNT(1)` would help with that!

Comment: @Mehran I have a situations analogous to yours in my database, and I assure you that this trick helps in my case (I go from 0.02s sec to 0.004sec). I'm sorry if it doesn't in yours...

Comment: Mehrah if it's a MyISAM table `COUNT(1)` will allow it to do a index scan instead of a table scan, because otherwise it needs to lookup the id. For InnoDB it is already part of the index anyway and it doesn't matter (assuming `id` is the PK).

Comment: @Mehran you have indexed only the 1-st 255 chars of `name`. How do you expect the DB to retrieve the entire thing from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query and use of indexes is that you refer to two different columns in your `SELECT` statement yet only have one column in your indexes, plus the use of a prefix on the index.

Try this (refer to just the name column):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY name;
```

With the following index (no prefix):

```
tbl (name)
```

Don't use a prefix on the index for this query because if you do, MySQL won't be able to use it as a covering index (will still have to hit the table).

If you use the above, MySQL will scan through the index on the `name` column, but won't have to scan the actual table data. You should see `USING INDEX` in the explain result.

This is as fast as MySQL will be able to accomplish such a task. The alternative is to store the aggregate result separately and keep it updated as your data changes.

Also, consider reducing the size of the `name` column, especially if you're hitting index size limits, which you most likely are hence why you're using the prefix. Save some room by not using UTF8 if you don't need it (UTF8 is 3 bytes per character for index).

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common question and key for solution lies in fact, that your table is growing.

So, first way would be: to create index by `name` column if it isn't created yet. **But:** this will solve your issue *for a time*.

More proper approach would be: to create separate statistics table like

```
tbl_counts
+------+-------+
| name | count |
+------+-------+
```

And store your counts separately. When changing (insert/update or delete) your data in `tbl` table - you'll need to adjust corresponding row inside `tbl_counts` table. This way allows you to get rid of performing `COUNT` query at all - but will need to add some logic inside `tbl` table.

To maintain integrity of your statistics table you can either use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) or do that inside application. This method is good if performance of `COUNT` query is much more important for you than your data changing queries (but overhead from changing `tbl_counts` table won't be too high)

Comment: Your solution is to store the results of aggregation which is not acceptable to me. Because the condition in `WHERE` can affect aggregation results while the conditions in it can be so diverse I can not even imagine.

Comment: @Mehran post your where conditions and schema. Being able to filter out most rows changes the question (and answer) entirely. For the question, as it is at the moment, this answer is correct and the only viable method (that I know of) to do this quickly.

Comment: Not sure why isn't it applicable. Store your data in separate table (like I've described), then select only those of them which are matching your condition. In fact, simple `JOIN` will do this work for you

Comment: For the moment I'm testing with no condition and yet I can not make MySQL use the index. And as I said the conditions are not fixed. The schema is posted.

Comment: So what do you mean _"the conditions are not fixed"_? And why does it prevent you from using `JOIN` with separate aggregate table?

Comment: @Mehran there is no fit-all solution for this. If you don't have WHERE conditions, the best you can hope for is an full index scan instead of a full table scan, which is not a huge improvement.